# Run an SSIS package remotely and programatically

Tags: sql-server, ssis

## Problem

I have developed an SSIS package for an ETL process, which I have deployed successfully to a remote server. I have windows and SQL logins for this server, but not admin. The data that this ETL process loads is generated on a different machine on a different domain early in the morning each day (i.e. before I get to work) and needs to be automatically loaded after the data generation process as soon as possible.

Currently, I manually run the ETL package in SSMS, and authenticate this by spoofing the windows user credentials on the remote server by launching SSMS with `runas.exe`. This is currently okay since we are in early development, but this is obviously not an acceptable solution in production. Hence, I would like to automate this process, since a) the data is extremely time sensitive and b) manually running this process is a PITA.

How should I go about automating execution of the ETL package such that:

1. Execution happens immediately after the data is available, and
2. No user input is required from me e.g. to enter passwords?

## Attempted solutions

Scheduling a SQL server agent job on a schedule is not an option, because of the time sensitivity. (Also my sysadmin seems to have not enabled/disabled the SQL server agent)

Continuing to use `runas.exe` is not an option either, as the `/netonly` flag, which is required, and the `/savecred` flag, which would prevent the need for manual password entry, are mutually exclusive.

`sqlcmd.exe` can be scripted to run with a SQL user and password (bad practice putting passwords in plain text, I know) but then running a stored procedure that calls the SSIS package fails, as windows authentication is required to run the package.

Comment: If time sensitivity were not an issue (and it's not), could you get your DBA to enable the Agent?  Because that's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice you to ask for working SQL Agent and create an Agent Job to run the package. This way has a lot of advantages:

- Native Windows user credentials management with proxy accounts
- You can configure specific values for package/project parameters, connection managers via SSMS interface
- You can use environment references of SSIS 2012 and above, and manage it via SSMS as well
- Job can be started on schedule or manually from SQL command. Thus you can automate package start.

In a nutshell - it is much easier to manage and you do not disclose user credentials needed to run the package - you might even do not know it.

For the alternative - you can try [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) from SysInternals tools. It allows to start program on another computer explicitly specifying username and password as `psexec \\server -u user -p password ...`. However, I would opt against it.